# Outputting specifically named file to same directory as infile - Perl

Tags: perl, directory, file-io

I've got the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $usage = "Usage: $0 <infile.txt> <outfile.txt>\n";
my $infile = shift or die $usage;
my $outfile = shift or die $usage;

open (my $data, "<", $infile) or die "There was a problem opening: $!";
my @primers = <$data>;
close $data;
chomp @primers;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);
my $strings = \@primers;
my $iter = combinations($strings, 2);
open(my $fh, '>', $outfile);
while (my $c = $iter->next) {
    print $fh join('',@$c) ."\n";
}
```

Which works just fine however I would prefer if the user did not have to specify the output directory and filename. Is there an easy way to get Perl to print the output to the same directory as infile but also giving the output file a specific name such as 'output.txt'?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

**SOLVED:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $usage = "Usage: $0 <infile.txt>\n";
my $infile = shift or die $usage;
use File::Basename;
my $DIR = dirname($infile);
my $outfile = $DIR . "/results.txt" or die $usage;

open (my $data, "<", $infile) or die "There was a problem opening: $!";
my @primers = <$data>;
close $data;
chomp @primers;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);
my $strings = \@primers;
my $iter = combinations($strings, 2);
open(my $fh, '>', $outfile);
while (my $c = $iter->next) {
    print $fh join('',@$c) ."\n";
}
print ("Finished. The results are located at $outfile\n\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to write the output to the same directory as  input file.  If so, you can use [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.2/lib/File/Basename.pm) module to get the directory of the input file.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
my $outfile=$infile . ".combinations"
```

Or, better yet, use stdin and stdout.

(also, check that your outfile was opened succesfully)

Comment: Thanks! That does help however I was more hoping I could have an input file that is say input.txt and the output is then output.txt rather than using the original input filename and adding to it. Is that possible?

Comment: In that case, @sunil_mlec has the answer you need. Use `dirname()` to extract the directory, then append your desired filename. Or, if you want to preserve teh extension (suffix), use `filepase()` to get both the directory and the extension.